# Contextual filters with Entity reference

Tags: views, entities

I have two content types called Basic Page and Contact Info.

- There are around 5 nodes from Contact Info with some contact info (phone/fax/email/IM) in the body field.
- In Basic Page content type there's an Entity Reference field that refers to Contact Info. So that for each page there would be a main contact person. When someone create a Basic Page node they can pick a Contact Info node from the dropdown (out of the 5 Contact Info nodes).

> Basic Page -> Contact Info (Basic Page content type refers to Contact
>   Info content type)

Then I created a block view (added to the sidebar of Basic pages) which displays the contact info associated with that node.

Added a Relationship in the view (Entity Reference: Referenced Entity)

Right now it's displaying all 5 contact info nodes, not just the one associated with that particular basic page node. I tried to tweak the Contextual filter and relationships but couldn't get it to work.

I have a feeling that the solution lies in the php code that goes in Provide default value -> php code section.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What's the contextual filter filtering on? Is it grabbing the node ID by default of the Basic Page? The relationship is basically going to make available the Contact Info attached to each *thing* the contextual filter filters for.

Comment: I tried various different combinations for the contextual filter, but none of them were working. (It won't display any Contact Info nodes). So I removed the contextual filter. As of now it's displaying all 5 Contact Info nodes in the sidebar. I just want to know what's the correct contextual filter that I need to apply to get only the correct 1 contact info node to display.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The contextual filter should be "content:nid"

The options should be set as follows...

> The Relationship should be your "Entity Reference: Referenced Entity"
>   relationship
>
> Under "When the filter value is NOT available" check "provide default
>   value" and select "Content ID from URL"
>
> Apply changes and save view.

I think this is the same thing Renee was saying, just in other words.

Hope this helps - I recently lost a weekend to figuring this out ; )

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that, but it didn't work. Here are some screenshots http://imgur.com/a/HoNVt

Comment: Have you tried creating a Referencing Entity instead of Referenced relationship? Also, you could work around fields by setting up a content type that shows State and City.

Comment: And, how are the fields set up? The field that shows the relationship data needs to have the relationship selected.

Comment: The fields shouldn't need to refer to the relationship (leave that setting "Do not use relationship")

Comment: This explanation may help: http://banoodle.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/drupal-7-views-how-to-make-content-aware-view-blocks/

Comment: @AnneBonham & Renee Thanks for your replies. I tried all the setting you suggested as well as the tutorial link, but nothing seems to be working. To answer your question on how to fields are set up I have the screenshots here. http://imgur.com/a/utWAz

Comment: I setup a test following what you did. It didn't work. So I just reversed the relationship in the view, changing referencED entity for contact info to referencING entity. These can be thought of like right and left joins in sql queries. I often get confused as to which to use in a situation (I just try it each way). After changing it to referencING I then had to edit the contextual filter, simply selecting the new relationship, and then everything is working as it should. Only the address for Mr. Blue is showing up on Mr. Blue's basic page. Here are the screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/eEShk

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you so much @AnneBonham . I've been trying to fix this for two days.

Comment: Thanks! It also works for Drupal 8!